# Use SimpleForm to have multiple options in Dropdown

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I'm using Ruby on Rails and trying to add make a dropdown form with only specified options, those options being states.

So far I have the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @location do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :address  %>
    <%= f.input :state  %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Add Location"  %>
  <% end %>
```

However, I want to add something like

```
    <%= f.input :state  %>
```

but only allowing all of the two letter abbreviations for all of the states in the USA (AL, AK, AZ, etc.)

Note: I have a location table with address and state as columns

Comment: Do you have a model called `State` that has all the `USA` states?  Can you share your model with their relationship as well?

Comment: @vee there is a location model containing the fields address and state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey you need this if you want it dinamyic values according your table states

****Table

```
 |states|
    |id| |name|
      1   ALASKA
      2   AK
      3   AZ
```

****In your controller:

```
  @states: State.all
```

****In your view:

```
 States: 
 <%= f.select "states",options_for_select(@states.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s ,t.id]}, params[:states].to_i ) %>
```

And If you want it with static values you should try:

```
<%= f.input :state, collection: ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out:

```
<%= f.input :state, collection: ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ'] %>
```

and so on...